# External interrupts of 8051 in c

Tags: interrupt-handling

This code written to display speed in mph by calculating number of external interrupts at INT0 for a particular time delay, works a part ie it just displays 'Read out:'
and then nothing.
I have seen 8051 derivatives page in c51 development tools. It shows me no needed information.
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0002a/c51_dv_8051deriv.htm
I have not understood why sometimes its written 
    void ex0_isr(void) interrupt 0 **using 2**

Can someone help me understand where am wrong?
Simulation is working fine.

```
//Calculating speed 

 #include <reg51.h>
 #include <string.h>


 void read(unsigned int q);
 void delay(void);
 void delay1(unsigned long int time);
 void SerInit();
 void SerTx(unsigned char x);
 void SerTx_str(unsigned char msg[]);

 unsigned char msg[]="Speed=  ";
 unsigned char buffer[12];
 sbit in_port=P3^2;
 sbit EDGT=TCON^0;
 unsigned char volatile count;
 unsigned int q;

  void ex0_isr(void) interrupt 0 
  {
    count++;
  }

  void timer0(void) interrupt 1
  {
     TR0=0;
  {



 void main()
  {

    SerInit();                 //serial initialisation
    SerTx_str("Read out:");    //send string to hyperterminal
    SerTx('\n');
    delay1(20);                //delay using loop
    SerTx('\r');
    in_port=1;             //input port pin
    EDGT=1;                //make IT0 =1 an edge triggered
    while(1)
    {
      count=0;             //initialize count
      IE=IE|0x81;          //enable global and INT0 
      delay();             //delay using timers for a time to measure  count
      SerTx_str("Dbg");   //check
      IE=IE&0xFE;          //disable INT0         
      q=count;               
      read(q);             //function called for ASCII conversion
      SerTx_str(msg);      //send message to terminal
      SerTx_str(buffer);   // send count to terminal
      SerTx('\n');
      delay1(2000);
      SerTx('\r');
    }
  }


 void read( unsigned int q)
  {
    unsigned int d1,d2,d3;
    d1=q%10;
    q=q/10;
    d2=q%10;
    d3=q/10;

    buffer[0]=d3+'0';
    buffer[1]=d2+'0';
    buffer[2]=d1+'0';
  }

  void delay(void)
  {
    unsigned int i;
    for(i=0;i<45;i++)  
    {
        TMOD=0x01;      //Timer 0, mode1(16 bit)
        TL0=0xFD;       //load TL0
        TH0=0x4B;       //load TH0 
        IE=IE|0x02;     //enable Timer 0 interrupt
        TR0=1;          //turn on Timer 0
       do
        {
         q=count;
        }
       while(TF0==0);   

    //if there's overflow ie, TF=1, goto interrupt 1 
    //
    //> TMOD=0x01;
      >  TL0=0xFD;
      >  TH0=0x4B;
      >  TR0=1;
      >  while(TF==0);
      >   TR0=0;
      >   TF0=0;  // previous code

    }
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, and your code could really be better formatted - reverse indentation is more like a prank than an indentation style. What do you want fixed? What do you mean "using 2

Comment: Since its not showing the count value, I'd like to know what might be causing the problem. I tried to find the bug but was unsuccessful. Is my interrupt service routine or the way I counted wrong? That's the format keil takes for comment. 'using 2' was used in a couple of sites I've seen which I couldn't why. If its needed, i'd like to know

Comment: It's not showing any count, or count is 0? You can just debug this like any normal embedded app. But you need to be more helpful. Post the log of what comes out the serial port. Do you even get the "Read out:" text? What is the observed results. And, tell me, what does "using 2" mean?? It's nowhere in your code. It's like you are just typing words without meaning. Also, you can indent the contents of your while loop, to adhere to common practice.

Comment: Is the while loop format ok now? The count value is expected to get updated for every interrupt and the last count value after the delay(); to be sent to the serial port which is not being displayed. yes.I get the "Read out:" text and cursor goes to new line and to the initial position of line. 'using 2' is used here in this link for timer 0 [link](keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_interruptfuncs.htm) Do you think that sort of thing is needed to void ex0_isr(void) interrupt 0? Have edited the original text.

Comment: The problem is either in your read() or your delay() function. If you put a SerTx("Dbg") immediately after the call to delay() and run it - does it show Dbg on the terminal? If so, then the problem is with read(), otherwise it is with delay(). Can you post your implementation of read()?

Comment: Yes. I added SerTx_str("Dbg"); right after delay(); . The output doesn't show 'Dbg'. I don't understand that if the problem is with the delay();, then how is the simulation working fine in keil as well as in the circuit for a separate program for LED blink with the same delay? I posted both the implementations of read() and delay().

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that by doing:

```
IE=0x81;
```

You are accidentally disabling the timer interrupts, which means that your delay() function never returns. I suspect you probably want to do something like this instead:

```
IE = IE | 0x01;          // enable INT0
delay();                 // delay using timers for a time to measure  count
IE = IE & 0xFE;          // disable INT0
```

Comment: IE = IE | 0x01;          // enable INT0
delay();                 // delay using timers for a time to measure  count
IE = IE | 0xFE;          // disable INT0  
Do you mean '&' instead of '|' in IE for disabling INT0?

Comment: Edited the code again where i put timer0 ISR.  I added timer 0 ISR so to prevent microcontroller from being tied down while polling in delay(). This modified code is exiting the 'for' loop regardless of there is overflow or not.

Comment: Yes, I meant &. I still think your problem is this: IE=0x80; My feeling is by doing this, you are disabling all other interrupts, which disables your timer interrupt. You will note, my answer suggested you do the bitwise operations INSTEAD of the assignment - not as well as it.

Comment: Okay. I gave IE=IE|0x81; for enabling global and INT0. This didn't work either. Supposing the microcontroller wouldn't respond to the external interrupt while it does polling, I changed the delay(); routine. It still the same.